# Drawing in a Java Panel

Tags: java, panel, draw

I'm new to Java programming and one of the exercises I have been given (we are allowed and encouraged to seek outside help) is to draw pixels doing different things in a `Panel` (not a `JPanel`).

I'm having trouble with two in particular, tracing a line of pixels around the perimeter of the panel and creating a spyrograph design (Trace a point on the circumference of a circle that rotates around a point on the circumference of another circle.)

I've gotten some basic functionality working, but there's problems with both. Can anyone see my error?

Here's my code and problems:

box around the perimeter - the pixels trace from the upper left hand corner, across the top to the right corner, down to the bottom right corner, across the bottom to the left corner, and then get stuck there:

```
drawBox(panel);}

public static void drawBox(Display panel) {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    while (x != 0 && y != 0){
        if (x < panel.getWidth() && y == 1){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            x++;
        }else if (x == panel.getWidth() && y != panel.getHeight()){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            y++;
        }else if (x != 0 && y == panel.getHeight()){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            x = x-1;
        }else if (x == 0 && y == panel.getHeight()){
            panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
            y = y - 1;
        }
    }
```

Now, for the circle on circle - mine doesn't really look like what it's supposed to - like what I mentioned above. It instead just draws a circle, but I believe the equation is correct. What am I doing wrong here?

```
drawCircles(panel); }

public static void drawCircles(Display panel) {
    int p = 250; // starting postion
    int R = 10; // radius of large circle
    int r = 5; // radius of small circle
    double x = 10;
    double y = 10;

    for (double t = 0.0; t < 100; t += 0.01) {
        x=(R+r)*Math.cos(t) + p*Math.cos((R+r)*(t/r));
        y=(R+r)*Math.sin(t) + p*Math.sin((R+r)*(t/r));
        double degrees = -Math.toDegrees((R+r)/r)*t;
        panel.drawNextPixel((int)x, (int) y);
    }
}
```

Comment: A http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be nice here. From quickly skimming over the code: Something like `(R+r)/r`, when all variables are of type `int`, may not produce the desired result. E.g. something like `10/6` will be `0`, because the result is truncated to `int`. Consider changing the variables to `double` if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the first one:

I think you probably meant to put

```
else if (x == 0 && y != 0) {
```

for the last else if.

Because after you pass the 3rd if clause, `x == 0` and `y == panel.getHeight()`, then after 1 more iteration, `x == 0`, and `y == panel.getHeight() - 1`.  These variable values satisfy none of the if clauses nor the while exit clause, creating an infinite loop.  The if clause described above works until y reaches the upper edge of the screen.

FYI, several for loops would be better here because you know exactly how many steps you need to take for each line. The first if clause, or the one creating the line going across the top would be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < panel.getWidth(); x ++) {
    panel.drawNextPixel(x, 0);
```

Also, `x = x - 1` is equivalent to `x --`.

For the second one, I don't know much about spirographs, let alone their equations.  Try doing a little research and checking your equations against several sites.  ([This site](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/spirographs.htm)
seems especially helpful for what you are trying to do.)  Also take Marco13's advice and change the variables to `double` if it's appropriate.